# Need Help printing five random numbers (like dice throws) for computer and player. I need to use ( randomeValue= ) statement seen in code

Tags: java, random, constructor

My code is only producing two random numbers and not five for player and computer like I need it to. Can anybody see the problem?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Die{

      private static int HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE=6;
      private static int LOWEST_DIE_VALUE=1;
      private int randomValue;

    public Die(){
                randomValue = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
        }

    private void generateRandom(){
              randomValue = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return randomValue;
      }
}

public class FiveDice {

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Die computer = new Die();
            Die player = new Die();

                System.out.println("Computer five random die values:");
                System.out.println("\tDie 1 rolled a " + computer.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\tDie 2 rolled a " + computer.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\tDie 3 rolled a " + computer.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\tDie 4 rolled a " + computer.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\tDie 5 rolled a " + computer.getValue() + " value");

                System.out.println("\nPlayer five random die values");
                System.out.println("\t\tDie 1 rolled a " + player.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\t\tDie 2 rolled a " + player.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\t\tDie 3 rolled a " + player.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\t\tDie 4 rolled a " + player.getValue() + " value");
                System.out.println("\t\tDie 5 rolled a " + player.getValue() + " value");   


        }

}
```

This is what the output:

> Computer five random die values:
>       Die 1 rolled a 5 value
>       Die 2 rolled a 5 value
>       Die 3 rolled a 5 value
>       Die 4 rolled a 5 value
>       Die 5 rolled a 5 value
>
> Player five random die values
>           Die 1 rolled a 4 value
>           Die 2 rolled a 4 value
>           Die 3 rolled a 4 value
>           Die 4 rolled a 4 value
>           Die 5 rolled a 4 value

I need each die for each player to be random numbers. Any help?

Comment: This is *java* not *javascript*. They are as closely related as *"Ham"* and *"Hamburger"*. Please tag responsibly according to what is represented in question

Comment: check the formula used for generating the numbers, it is not flawless: 1. since 100 is not divisible by 6, you are getting an (slightly) uneven distribution of the random numbers. 2. it will not work correctly when `LOWEST_DIE_VALUE` is not 1

Answer (score 0):

Because randomNumbers are getting generated 2 times because of the 2 constructor calls when you're creating objects of Die class.

One possibility is you may use the generateRandom() method inside the `computer.getValue()` method to get a random number everytime. Also, use the instance variable `randomValue` to generate random variables in this case.

In such case, modify your code as shown below:

```
private void generateRandom(){
              this.randomValue = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
    }

public int getValue(){
        generateRandom();  // add this call to method generateRandom();
        return this.randomValue;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you AM_I-Helpful and Darhsan for your quick response. I was able to figure out how to get it to work with Am_I_Helpfuls modifications.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @ScottD - You may like to accept the answer if it helped. See how to accept an answer ---> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: AM_I_Helpful, thank you for your help.  I'm new to Java and could really use your help with the why? adding this. seemed to fix my code.  Can you please tell me why? I don't quite understand/

Comment: @ScottD - Because you're not using the method which performed Random Selection of the number; once you called the `generateRandom()` method from the `getValue()`, you confirm everytime you call `getValue()`, the selection is a randomly generated number. For further detail, you need to learn the OOP Skills, which is a broad topic and can't be discussed here.

Comment: @ScottD - You may like to accept the answer if it helped. See how to accept an answer ---> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The reason being, you are only generating the value in constructor and return the same value every time, e.g:

```
public Die(){
    randomValue = ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
}

public int getValue(){
    return randomValue;
}
```

Here, `randomValue` gets initialised only once (in constructor) and hence, same value gets returned whenever `getValue` method is called.

If you want different values every time then you can directly call `generateRandom` method and change it to return `int`. In fact, there is no need to have `randomValue` as an instance variable as value does not need to be preserved. You can instead make `generateRandom` static and call it directly from outside, e.g.:

```
public class Die{

    private static int HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE=6;
    private static int LOWEST_DIE_VALUE=1;

    public static int generateRandom(){
        return ((int)(Math.random() * 100) % HIGHEST_DIE_VALUE + LOWEST_DIE_VALUE);
    }

}
```

And call it in main method using: `Die.generateRandom();`